# Exception occurred executing command line while running Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

While running a program in Eclipse I got an Error message,

```
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" 
(in directory "C:\VijeeGuna\MuleWorkspace\JDBCTrial"): 
CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
```

I have checked my classpath, it is correct to the best of my knowledge. I am not able to resolve the error. Please provide suggestions,

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code generating the error.